# Query "where" with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, where-clause

I've in my app, posts as ideas, and these ideas belongs to an activity and a status.
And I want to sort them by activity for one status so I did in my controller

```
@idees_en_place = Idee.where(statut_id= "2")
@activites = Activite.all
```

And in my view :

```
<% @activites.each do |activite| %>
  <div class="idee en-place col-lg-5" style="background:#<%= activite.color%>">
    <h2><%= activite.name %></h2>
    <p>
     <% @idees_en_place.where(activite_id = activite.id).limit(3).each do |idee| %>
     <div class="idee">
       <h6><%= link_to idee.title, idee %></h6>
      </div>
     <% end %>
  </p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But that doesn't work, in each part of an activity the ideas are not sorted.
I think it's a little mistake but I don't know how to resolve this

Comment: should be: `@idees_en_place = Idee.where(statut_id: 2)`

Comment: Can you add how you mapped your models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@idees_en_place = Idee.where(statut_id= "2")
```

There are two problems with this code.

First, `id` is a `Integer` type (unless you've defined it as `String`).
Second, its a key value you pass to `where` clause, and you pass these either as

```
:status_id => 2 # old hashrocket syntax
```

or

```
status_id: 2 # new syntax
```

The same goes with this part

```
@idees_en_place.where(activite_id = activite.id)
```

it should be

```
@idees_en_place.where(activite_id: activite.id)
```

Comment: Thanks !
But now, no ideas are displayed

Comment: @MilletoSimon this is a question to you and associations between models in your app, not to me :) Most likely there is no `Idea`s with `status_id` of `2`. Please accept the answer if it taught you something about quering db

Answer (score 0):

In **Controller**

```
@idees_en_place = Idee.where(statut_id: 2)
@activites = Activite.all
```

In **View**

```
<% @activites.each do |activite| %>
  <div class="idee en-place col-lg-5" style="background:#<%= activite.color%>">
    <h2><%= activite.name %></h2>
    <p>
     <% @idees_en_place.where(activite_id: activite.id).limit(3).each do |idee| %>
     <div class="idee">
       <h6><%= link_to idee.title, idee %></h6>
      </div>
     <% end %>
  </p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: One should _never_ execute queries in views. On 100 activities there will be 100 queries against database executed.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanna point out that you will run into an N+1 queries issue, to avoid this you should preload every thing, instead of doing queries in the views.

**The controller:**

```
#change if the association name is different
@activites = Activite.includes(:idees)
```

**The view**

```
<% @activites.each do |activite| %>
  <div class="idee en-place col-lg-5" style="background:#<%= activite.color%>">
    <h2><%= activite.name %></h2>
    <p>
     <% activitie.idees[0..2].each do |idee| %>
     <div class="idee">
       <h6><%= link_to idee.title, idee %></h6>
      </div>
     <% end %>
  </p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Notes:**

I've used the `[0..2]` format because I wanted to avoid ActiveRecord from doing a new query, another method would be limiting the query using something like this

```
@activites = Activite.includes(:idees).merge(Idee.limit(3))
```

Then you won't need to use any limitation in the views, but I haven't tested this, don't have access on a rails machine right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following code will help you:

Since your Idee belong to activity and status that's why you have activity_id and status_id in your Idee table.

you may find out all the idee for a status by using:

```
Idee.where(:status_id => 2)
```

and you can sort Idee in Asc or desc order by using order

```
idees = Idee.join(:activity).where(:status_id => 2).order(:activity_id => :asc)
idees = Idee.join(:activity).where(:status_id => 2).order(:activity_id => :desc)

<% activity_id = -1%>
<@idees.each do |idee| %>
  <div class="idee en-place col-lg-5" style="background:#<%= idee.activite.color%>">
  <h2><%= idee.activity.name %></h2>
  <p>
    <% if activity_id != idee.activity_id  %>
      <% activity_id = idee.activity.id %>
      <% counter = 0 %>
    <% end %>
    <% if counter < 3 %>
      <% counter = counter + 1%>
      <div class="idee">
        <h6><%= link_to idee.title, idee %></h6>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </p>
</div>
```